# what is auto-fit in grid-tempelate-columns?

Tags: html, css

i am practicing grid layout in CSS. i have studied this syntax:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));`
can anybody describe this line i have used to create responsive grid.

Comment: Read [CSS TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/)

Comment: @HR01M8055 Hey thanks buddy for this useful article you make my day again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repeat() => is used in grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows. It repeats the fragment according to your screen size.

auto-fit =>  it will fit as many columns on your screens according to your screen size.

minmax() => this function will choose a size range greater than or equal to min and less than or equal to max.which means between 300px and 1fr(fr = fractional unit default size of a column).

this line of css will create responsive columns according to your screen size and adjust the number of columns as the screen size increases or decreases

Comment: can you please guide more about minmax because i have visited the developers.mozilla.org documentation but it is too much complicated to understand for the absolute beginners...